# Addup differently byte-sized fields in Java?

Tags: java

I am coding some sort of packet which has different fields with different length in bytes.

So field1 is 2 byte long field2 is 3 bytes long field3 is 6 bytes long and when I addup these fields, I should be getting 11 bytes in length.

But I have no idea how I can declare something with this byte long.

Comment: By "all above answers" he means answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098097/how-can-i-assign-2-bytes-to-a-variable-in-java

Comment: This should not be its own question; go edit the original http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098097 instead.  To do so, you need to sign in with the same account you used to create the other question (currently you are split between user IDs 134939 and 135155), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598 if you need help with that.

Comment: You probably want to change the name of this question to something like "Designing a protocol at the byte level in Java". Idk... "Bytes in Java?" is really bad though.

Comment: Ugh at this point everything is so messed up. You should have edited the original question, but the way your questions are worded, they are so different. Both of them could use name changes, quite frankly.

Comment: Are people downvoting this because the question was split up over two posts? Other than that, it is a perfectly legit question.

Answer (score 5):

Use an array:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[11];
```

Comment: I already knew about the byte primitive, but thinking about it now, I wonder if we could use it to implement a uint class...

Answer (score 2):

How's about:

```
byte[] arr = new byte[11];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a class to represent your packet:

```
public class Packet
{
   public byte[] Field1, Field2, Field3;

   public Packet(byte[] packetBytes) 
   {
      ByteBuffer packet = ByteBuffer.wrap(packetBytes);
      Field1 = new byte[2];
      Field2 = new byte[3];
      Field3 = new byte[6];
      packet.get(Field1, 0, 2);
      packet.get(Field2, 2, 3);
      packet.get(Field3, 5, 6);
   }
}
```

ByteBuffer is good for byte-manipulation.

Comment: First... did I miss something... "struct" in java?? Also, isn't manipulting the actual ByteBuffer better, and creating a wrapper class around it? Instead of using get() and filling byte arrays, you could use packet.getInt(); packet.getChar(); etc etc for whatever types are nested in the packet.

Comment: whoops - I started answering in C# - then switched to Java.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that java.nio.ByteBuffer is typically better for this sort of thing. It has nice methods for dealing with interpreting the bytes in the buffer. The docs are [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(11);
```

Check out the docs and look at the nice methods such as `getInt()` and `getChar()`.

Comment: Also, before you go making your own protocol and stuff to parse and interpret it, you may want to check something out like Google's Protocol Buffers: http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html. They sound like they could get the job done and the code for handling the protocol messages could be less cumbersome. It does add more dependencies in your code and such (there is a protocol buffer compiler you would need to invoke), but I find them easy to use :-).

Answer (score 0):

Java has a limited collection of primitive types, which all have a fixed size. You can see a list of them [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). That means you can't decide how many bytes your variable will consist of.

Of course, as others have already mentioned, you can always create a `new byte[11]`. Note that Java's `byte` is signed, however. It goes from -128 to 127, not from 0 to 255.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the utility classes in [Javolution](http://javolution.org/) for dealing with binary protocol streams such as this.  They've come in handy for me several times when dealing with low-level binary streams.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably design your code to separate the message you want to manipulate in java from the wire level format you need to read/write.

e.g. If you have a ScreenResolution concept, you could represent it in java with a ScreenResolution class:

```
public class ScreenResolution {
   public int height;
   public int width;
}
```

This class is easy to work with in Java. Transforming this to a packet that can be transmitted over a network/saved to a file, etc. according to some file format or protocol is another concern.
Say the height and width is to be laid out in 3 bytes each, with some ID and length for the "wire format", you make something like

```
public byte[] marshalScreenResolution(ScreenResolution obj) {
   byte[] buf = new byte[9];
 //length of this packet, 2 bytes
   buf[0] = 0;
   buf[1] = 9;
   buf[2] = SCREENRESOLUTION_OPCODE;
   //marshal the height/width , 3 least significant bytes.
   buf[3] = (obj.height&0xff0000) >> 16;
   buf[4] = (obj.height&0x00ff00) >> 8;
   buf[5] = (obj.height&0x0000ff) ;
   buf[6] = (obj.width&0xff0000) >> 16;
   buf[7] = (obj.width&0x00ff00) >> 8;
   buf[8] = (obj.width&0x0000ff) ;

   return buf;
}
```

And you make a demarshalScreenResolution function for going from a packet to a ScreenResolution object. The point is you decouple the representation in java from the external representation, and you assemble the fields in the external representation using bytes + some basic bit fiddling.